# Custom Lexicon and Thesaurus files not loaded in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am trying to test fulltext search in Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Standard edition. I stored the needed files in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn
```

and

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\FTData
```

FYI the datafiles are stored somewhere else on another disk.

**Wrt to the Lexicon/Thesaurus**

On the tsenu.xml I tried both with comment out and removing comment
The files are encoded UCS2 LE BOM (that was the encoding of the original file. Concerning the thesaurus file I started by writing in notepad, saving in unicode. This is not working and so I moved to the above mentioned encoding).

But after having run:

```
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'restart_all_fdhosts';
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'update_languages';
EXEC sys.sp_fulltext_load_thesaurus_file 1033;
```

I built a table with the following words:

```
running
IE
```

Then Run

```
Q1.
select * from dbo.THES_TEST where Contains(Word,'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"run")');
```

Q1 returns one line

```
Q2.
select * from dbo.THES_TEST where Contains(Word,'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"jog")');
```

Q2 returns ZERO lines

What's wrong?

**Wrt to the Custom Dictionary**

The lexicon `Custom1033.lex` contains x-rated.

Nevertheless the query below returns 3 lines:

```
select 'A' as A,*
 from sys.dm_fts_parser('x-rated', 1030,0,0);
```

Why?